# Coordinates2Politics in Datasciencetoolkit Python doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, geocoding

I am using the Datasciencetoolkit in Python3 to get the county out of latitude and longitude.
However, the API doesn't want to accept my input, an always thinks that the latitude would be 0. Any ideas?

```
import pydstk
dstk = pydstk.DSTK()

pos = "32.718, -117.134"
x = dstk.coordinates2politics(pos) 
print (x)
```

This is the output:

[{'politics': None, 'location': {'latitude': 0.0, 'longitude': -117.134}}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong variable type

insted string use list

```
import pydstk
dstk = pydstk.DSTK()

pos = [32.718, -117.134]
x = dstk.coordinates2politics(pos) 
print (x)
```

Output:

```
[  
   {  
      u'politics':[  
         {  
            u'code':u'usa',
            u'type':u'admin2',
            u'friendly_type':u'country',
            u'name':u'United States'
         },
         {  
            u'code':u'us06',
            u'type':u'admin4',
            u'friendly_type':u'state',
            u'name':u'California'
         },
         {  
            u'code':u'06_075',
            u'type':u'admin6',
            u'friendly_type':u'county',
            u'name':u'San Francisco'
         },
         {  
            u'code':u'06_67000',
            u'type':u'admin5',
            u'friendly_type':u'city',
            u'name':u'San Francisco'
         },
         {  
            u'code':u'06_08',
            u'type':u'constituency',
            u'friendly_type':u'constituency',
            u'name':u'Eighth district,
            CA'
         },
         {  
            u'code':u'Castro-Upper Market|San Francisco|CA',
            u'type':u'neighborhood',
            u'friendly_type':u'neighborhood',
            u'name':u'Castro-Upper Market'
         }
      ],
      u'location':{  
         u'latitude':37.769456,
         u'longitude':-122.429128
      }
   }
]
```

Comment: thank you, that did it! Do you use the datasciencetoolkit as a VM? Right now i have the problem that the 22Gb .box file is unpacked to over 60Gb and then it stops because my harddrive is full. Do you have any idea how much storage I need?

Comment: I did not use this, you have to check.